# File system Inode flags: difference between FS_IOC_GETFLAGS and FS_IOC_FSGETXATTR

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

What is the difference between `FS_IOC_GETFLAGS` and `FS_IOC_FSGETXATTR` `ioctl` commands? What flags do both return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Linux context, `FS_IOC_GETFLAGS` and `FS_IOC_FSGETXATTR` both retrieve inode flags.

`GETFLAGS` is the older `ioctl`, and comes originally from `ext2` (again, in Linux); it manipulates a 32-bit value and has thus limited expansion capabilities — there aren’t many unused bits available.

`FSGETXATTR` comes from XFS, and was recently (2016) moved from XFS to the shared VFS layer. It uses a data structure, `struct fsxattr`, which allows for more values and more expansion.

Both of these, and the meanings of the data they return, are defined in [`linux/fs.h`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/fs.h). The `GETFLAGS` flags are additionally documented in [`ioctl_iflags(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_iflags.2.html). Common values between the two correspond mostly to `GETFLAGS` flags which were historically supported by [XFS](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/xfs.5.html): “append only”, “no atime updates”, “no dump”, “immutable”, and “synchronous updates”.

Note that in both cases support varies from one file system to another, and some flags aren’t actually supported at all.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. Great explanation. One question more, how to set these xflags via linux cli?

Comment: Two CLI tools supports `fsxattr`-specific flags, as far as I’m aware: `chattr` allows setting project-related flags, and `xfs_fsr` allows settings XFS flags (but only on XFS). Some tools (Docker, Ceph...) support `fsxattr` flags internally, but I don’t know whether they allow manipulating them externally.

Answer (score -2):

`FS_IOC_GETFLAGS` is an interface to access BSD style file flags. It just uses a much worse interface than *BSD, since you need to open the file in order to get access. *BSD has these informations in `struct stat`, so if you like to get the related information in /dev/ entries on Linux, you may cause a tape drive to rewind it's medium.

`FS_IOC_FSGETXATTR`is a similar but apparently incompatible interface from XFS that seems to be supported by ext4 as well since September 2015.

Conclusion: both interfaces are badly designed since they need to open the file in order to get access. The maintainers do not seem to care about their interfaces since they do not inform important users like `star` which is able to back up and restore the flags from the `FS_IOC_GETFLAGS`interface.

Comment: Not sure who’s downvoting these answers... Do you have a pointer to the extended attribute proposal in question?

Comment: Hi, I fixed my text, it seems that I was mistaken since the name of the second call is **very** similar to the withdrawn xattr interface. There seem to be some people who follow me and downvote all my answers. This was the POSIX.1e ACL draft. You may try: https://simson.net/ref/1997/posix_1003.1e-990310.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I wondered if you were referring to POSIX.1e. The difference in interfaces between the BSDs and Linux is indeed unfortunate...

Comment: well, Linux could fix the interface without becoming incompatible to older Linux versions: It would just need to implement and document that an open() with the open flag `O_SEARCH` but without `O_RDONLY` or `O_WRONLY` will be allowed to issue a `FS_IOC_GETFLAGS` `iotcl()` but will not cause any side effects in the `open()` call. `O_SEARCH` has been introduced in POSIX from my proposal similar to an open method from UNOS that did not have `stat()` but only `fstat()`.